# Oracle - creating a Materialized View

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I'm reading some articles, even some answers here on stack, but i still have some issues. I'll post my MV code for possible analysis:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW some_materialized_view
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH sysdate
NEXT '2011-12-01' + 31
WIDTH PRIMARY KEY
AS my_query
```

The error is:

```
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

Am i forgeting something? The only thing i want is that my MV update every month beggining. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: "This code is not working for me" - Error message? A description of what "Not Working" looks like to you would be helpful.

Comment: The only error i get is:

00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntax errors in your command.

The clause `WIDTH PRIMARY KEY` should be `WITH PRIMARY KEY` (you have a typo on `WITH`)

The `NEXT` clause is using a date literal which requires the `date` keyword:

`NEXT DATE '2011-12-01' + 31`.

So the full command should be:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW some_materialized_view
REFRESH
  COMPLETE
  START WITH SYSDATE
  NEXT DATE '2011-12-01' + 31
  WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS <your query here>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, was that mistakes! But i still want to know how to do to update every month beggining..

Comment: you can use NEXT add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)

Comment: Thanks dude, exactly what i want!!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consult the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6002.htm) first, esp for syntax questions.  Everything you're asking + more is there.  The language reference docs are very helpful once you're used to them, and you just might learn a few new things regarding what you're researching.